# Data Binding nested custom layouts

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I'm trying to implement DataBinding as much as possible. At the moment, I'm using it just like I'd to with ButterKnife, but in the future I'll actually bind some data.I've successfully reproduced the issue with the following SSCCE:

*CustomLayout.java*

```
public class CustomLayout extends LinearLayout {

  CustomLayoutBinding mBinding;

  public CustomLayout(Context context) {
      this(context, null, 0);
  }

  public CustomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      this(context, attrs, 0);
  }

  public CustomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
      init(context);
  }

  private void init(Context context) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
      mBinding = CustomLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater, this, true);
  }
}
```

*custom_layout.xml*

```
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="Test text"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:src="@android:drawable/btn_star"/>
</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

The idea is that I can reuse this layout easily, keeping it modular. Now, the problem arises when I create the following activity:

*CustomActivity.java*

```
public class CustomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  ActivityCustomBinding mBinding;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(CustomActivity.this, R.layout.activity_custom);
  }
}
```

*activity_custom.xml*

```
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <es.test.sample.CustomLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

In this situation, the application crashes due to the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: view tag isn't correct on view:null
at es.test.sample.databinding.CustomLayoutBinding.bind(CustomLayoutBinding.java:98)
at android.databinding.DataBinderMapper.getDataBinder(DataBinderMapper.java:27)
at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.bind(DataBindingUtil.java:185)
at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.bindToAddedViews(DataBindingUtil.java:299)
at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:118)
at es.test.sample.databinding.CustomLayoutBinding.inflate(CustomLayoutBinding.java:85)
at es.test.sample.databinding.CustomLayoutBinding.inflate(CustomLayoutBinding.java:82)
at es.test.sample.CustomLayout.init(CustomLayout.java:34)
at es.test.sample.CustomLayout.<init>(CustomLayout.java:28)
at es.test.sample.CustomLayout.<init>(CustomLayout.java:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:465)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:172)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:186)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:334)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:345)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:245)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:324)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$70(RenderTask.java:659)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've seen some other questions about this view:null thing, but none of them worked for me. Specifically, I've tried the following:

*CustomLayout.class*

```
public class CustomLayout extends LinearLayout {

  CustomLayoutBinding mBinding;

  public CustomLayout(Context context) {
      this(context, null, 0);
  }

  public CustomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      this(context, attrs, 0);
  }

  public CustomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
      init(context);
  }

  private void init(Context context) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
      inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, this, true);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
      super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
      mBinding = CustomLayoutBinding.bind(getRootView());
  }
}
```

It won't resolve this issue.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: Try Android Studio 2.3RC1. The bug should be fixed.

Comment: Ok, I guess now we're one step closer to solving this bug. 2.3RC1 doesn't cause app to crash, but the exception persist as a render error, therefore the app doesn't show CustomLayout.

Comment: What is the new render error?

Comment: As I said, the exception persists as a render error. It outputs the same stacktrace `java.lang.RuntimeException: view tag isn't correct on view:null`, although when run the application doesn't crash, showing instead a blank view.

Comment: A bit late to the party I know but I think there is a <data/> tag missing in activity_custom.xml, isn't it?